# In Grails how to upload java object arrays in aws cloudsearch?

Tags: java, grails, amazon-cloudsearch

In Grails(which provide complete set of plugins) also provide searchable plugin which is sufficient to do indexing and searching job. Now since we are moving to AWS cloudsearch we have achieved how to search(based on lucene) any object. Now I was getting error while uploading the documents(which is actually array of objects)?
What is the best way to upload any array of object(java) which maps to the domain of the cloudsearch? This is to achieve the bulkupload from grails.

Answer (score 0):

CloudSearch does not support objects.  It supports the following types, as well as arrays of each type (except latlon).

- date
- double
- int
- latlon
- literal
- text

[Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/configuring-index-fields.html)

My team is switching to AWS Elasticsearch service for this and other reasons.  CloudSearch hasn't seen an update since January, 2013 and there's no indication that they plan to make any updates or improvements to it.